# How to clear a hashmap in Android

Tags: android, memory-management, hashmap

Below is the reference code

```
public static Map<String, Long > map1 = new HashMap<String, Long >();
```

if i call map1.clear() , will all elements of hashmap become eligible for GC or do i need to set every element of the map explicitly to null ?

Comment: yes .. thank you .. i have thought that clear function given in the question is written by the user ..now understood it is the code of default clear.

Answer (score 0):

`hashmap.clear()` just clears all the data of the HashMap to make it reusable again.Here reusable means the same object can be reused again.So I dont think there is any role of `GC` here.

Comment: my intention of mentioning GC is ..in java if objects are still referred ..they will not be eligible for Garbage collection ..when we dont make the array object to null , then the refrence is not released and hence memory leak .. some one please correct me if i am wrong ..